# Google maps makes no sound when interupting music etc

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation, vlc

Was there an update to google maps recently that affected this? I made no changes to my phone, and before when I was listening to a podcast using VLC or Samsung Music, google maps voice would just mute the audio and play over it. Now it still mutes the audio but just doesn't give directions, and then my music just picks up afterwards.